# OSError when I'm trying to connect bluetooth. How can I fix it? ( Connect Board bluetooth HC-06 )

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, python-requests

So when I trying to connect bluetooth. This is my code:

```
import subprocess
import bluetooth

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(duration=4, lookup_names=True, flush_cache=True, 
lookup_class=False)


name = "HC - 06"    # Device name
addr = "20:17:11:20:28:17"     # Device Address
port = 1         # RFCOMM port
passkey = "1234" # passkey of the device you want to connect

# kill any "bluetooth-agent" process that is already running
subprocess.call("kill -9 `pidof bluetooth-agent`",shell=True)
#  Start a new "bluetooth-agent" process where XXXX is the passkey
status = subprocess.call("bluetooth-agent " + passkey + " &",shell=True)

# Now, connect in the same way as always with PyBlueZ
try:
    s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
    s.connect((addr,port))
except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as err:
# Error handler
    pass
```

And it have an error like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/Code/number.py", line 20, in <module>
     s.connect((addr,port))
  File "C:\Users\huuhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 96, in connect
    bt.connect (self._sockfd, addr, port)
OSError: A
```

Please help me to fix it. Thanks you !!!

Comment: This is a code I'm trying to connet bluetooth board "HC - 06"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some explanation instead of using comments as you did.

Comment: `kill -9` and `bluetooth-agent` look like commands on a Linux system, while in your error message you have `C:\Users\huuhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bluetooth` which looks like it is on a Windows system. Which type of system are your unning this on?